# Spring MVC portlet IBM WPS

Tags: spring-mvc, portlet, websphere-portal, spring-portlet-mvc

In my job there was a debate about using Spring MVC portlet with IBM WPS, and architect is insisting  it is have problem to use it without providing any reference, anyone have any input in this discussion based on actual experience, or any reference talking about issue of using Spring MVC portlet with IBM WPS, or have any reference can I use to show comparison of using Spring MVC portlet or other frameworks?

Answer (score 0):

The standard Spring portlet MVC portlets work well. However they don't offer the fancy components offered by JSF frameworks.

Check out the [spring documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/portlet.html) for getting started. You can check the outdated [pet portal](http://springframework.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/springframework/spring/samples/petportal/), not sure if it is working with 3.2 though.